# UIScrollView too close on home bar

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

Whenever I run my iOS app on a device that has a home bar, the bottom of a UIScrollView or one of its descendants will render too low.

My app has a bottom navigation. I made the scroll view constrained to the safe area on the Y axis. It contains a container view (Cv For Home) in which I load a subview:

[image: parent view]

The container view is constrained to the superview (scroll view), though.

In my child storyboard's subview I have a collection view, that I have to constrain a lot from the bottom of the superview away, oddly enough. Otherwise it will not display entirely on the devices:

[image: child view]

That's weird, but it works, unless I run the app on a device with home bar. I think this might be related, but I'm pretty new to constrains and I can't get it right for some reason.

The result, then, looks like this:

[image: the problem]

As you can see the last cells are hidden below the bottom navigation on the middle and right device. Both have a home bar, the left device does not. How can I fix this?

EDIT: The bottom navigation looks like this:

[image: bottom navigation]

I also tried to set the bottom constraint of the scroll view to the top of the bottom navigation, but that was resulting in the same issue.

EDIT 2: Taking a look at the *Debug View Hierarchy* reveals in fact, my Safe Area is too long, so it seems that it has a fixed height and using a bottom constraint on the bottom edge of the Safe Area will break if there is a home bar:

[image: inspecting the safe area]

The parent UIView has the correct size.

Comment: You almost certainly should constrain to the Top of your "bottom navigation bar" ... but I'm curious -- why are you putting collectionViews inside a scrollView?

Comment: @DonMag There is a segue between the scrollView and the collectionView, other stuff could be in place of the collectionView that needs to be scrollable. `CvForHome` will embed a `HomeVC` which loads a subview that contains my scroll view. Yes, it's weird and messed up, it's not my creation, I just have to deal with it now, so I don't know what the devs thought when making this, but they haven't thought things through as I believe. As said, I tried to constrain to the top of the bottom navigation bar, but the result is the same.

Comment: The problem, then, is likely how the collectionView is constrained in the scrollView. Without seeing how you are doing that, it's tough to say. Use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the layout at run-time.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you for showing me the _Debug View Hierarchy_, this was really helpful to make an interesting discovery. I still don't have a solution, but at least I'm knowing what I deal with, right now. I updated my question to show off my discovery.